# Django - Issues passing String correctly to template after replacing characters in view

Tags: python, django, string, html

I'm having a bizarre issue with passing a particular string from a view to a template.

The string originates from a form, and contains text that I want to simplify into a split-able string later. So, I substitute potential separator characters with a comma like so:

```
# views.py

mystring = myform.cleanedData['mystring']
mystring = str(mystring)  # convert from unicode
mystring = mystring.replace("\n", ",").replace("\r\n", ",").replace(" ", ",").replace(";", ",")

# Then I pass it to the template:
return render(request, 'html/mytemplate.html', {'mystring': mystring})
```

Now, take this form data for example:

```
%15
%16
```

If I print out *mystring* to a file just before rendering the template, it looks like this:

```
%15,%16
```

All good so far. The problem, though, comes from trying to render this string into the template. If I try to render the string like this:

```
{{ mystring }}
```

The result is this (leading spaces included):

```
    %15
,%16
```

It preserves the comma, but adds some other funky stuff, which I don't want because it makes some of my JS get pretty darn confused. I've tried to prevent escaping with the ***safe*** filter, but it doesn't seem to change anything in this case. Another thing to note is that if the original form data is already correctly formatted, i.e. "%15,%16", it works just fine and passes the string as intended.

Any ideas? I've done quite a bit of logging inside my views, but it seems to be fine up until I render it to the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after looking at my own example code here, I realized what the issue was.

I needed to swap the order of `replace("\n", ",")` with `replace("\r\n", ",")`, ensuring that the latter occurs first. The issue was caused by the `\n` escapes being replaced, and then not being able to find any occurrences of `\r\n`, therefore leaving all of the `\r`s in the text.